# Ubuntu server login loop in shell after deleting zsh

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server

I have a PC I'm using as a linux server (Ubuntu 16.10), to which I ssh / run nginx etc. Today I tried to remove zsh (the default shell, via apt-get purge) hoping it would default back to either to bash or fish shell. Instead, I now cannot ssh into the server (wrong password), and when I use the same password to login directly to the server (as in not via ssh, literally hooking up the server to a monitor) it flashes some text and prompts me to login again.

I've tried holding shift on boot, didn't do anything.

Also, no FTP.

And I don't have a password for the root user or any other user.

I'd heavily prefer not to wipe the whole server, Is there a way I can access it and fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have physical access to the PC, you can boot it from live cd (or thumb drive) and mount the HDD or take out the HDD and put it in another machine, and then edit /etc/passwd and/or reset the password.

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that!

Answer (score 1):

As [@Maadinsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061491/maadinsh) said, this is the correct answer:

1. Boot into a linux liveCD (Ubuntu liveCD, etc.)
2. Mount the Linux system partition (The boot looped Ubuntu-Server, not the liveCD ubuntu / other distro)
3. cd into /etc/ and chmod passwd to let you edit it
4. Change the default shell for your user (at the end of the line) from the nonexisting shell to an existing one.
5. Save passwd
6. Reboot the server.